# Certificate issue on remote desktop

Tags: authentication, remote-desktop, certificate, mstsc

Please see this link :  [Certificate issue on remote desktop](http://www.faultwire.com/solutions-Windows_7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-*1368.html)

I have 2 PCs with Windows 7 Ultimate...  (both are in NETHOME)
PC 1 : computer name = alfa -> (main pc) , IP = 192.168.0.1
PC 2 : computer name = beta-lap ->(laptop) , IP = 192.168.0.2
connection type : cross cable ...

When I want to remote one of these PC's from the other, I get the below error:

```
Full Title :  
Remote Desktop Connection    
Body Text :  
The remote computer could not be authenticated due to problems with its security certificate. It may be unsafe to proceed.

Certificate name

Name in the certificate from the remote computer:

blablabla

Certificate errors

The following errors were encountered while validating the remote computer's certificate:

The certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority.

Do you want to connect despite these certificate errors?

Don't ask me again for connections to this computer
```

I can bypass it by checking despite these certificate errors and view the remote computer, but is this normal?

**how can i fix this issue?**
Besides why do I have an attention icon on both network connection icons in system tray of both PCs?
What is the problem about this little network?

Comment: Where did you get this certificate from? If you inspect the certificate, what is the CN in it?

Comment: dear @wolfgangsz thanks for comment :  both of them have this certificate error ... -> what is CN?

Comment: CN is the common name that this certificate was issued for. It should be the fully qualified host name of the machine using it.

Comment: where can i find it?

Comment: i installed both certificate on both machines in trusted ... / but still have this issue!  and what about the attention icon?

Comment: Answer the question: where did you get the certificates from? When you get the error message, you should be offered to inspect the certificate's details, that's where the CN should be shown.